# PUT request with subdocuments

Tags: python, mongodb, api, rest

I'm currently creating a PUT request for my backend API to allow users to add restaurants to a dataset. Currently, in the dataset, the lat and lng of the restaurant is under geometry > location. Im unsure how I would specify this in the backend API.

[image: Bellow see how the LNG and lat values are stores in mongodb]

Here is what I have for the backend API so far:

```
    @app.route("/api/v1.0/restaurant", methods = ["POST"])
    
    def add_new_restaurant():
        if "restaurant" in request.form and "city" in request.form:
            new_restaurant = {
                "restaurant": request.form["restaurant"],
                "city": request.form["city"],
                "reviews": []
            }
            new_restaurant_id = restaurants.insert_one(new_restaurant)
            new_restaurant_link = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/restaurants/" \  +          str(new_restaurant_id.inserted_id)
            return make_response( jsonify(  { "url" : new_restaurant_link } ), 201 )
```

Comment: Are you sure that this a Django code?

Comment: I don't believe it is, does it need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nested object so you can insert it as such. You can represent it in a dict with a `geometry` key that maps to a `dict` value, which has a `location` key that maps to another dict that specifies that lat/long.

```py
new_restaurant = {
    "restaurant": request.form["restaurant"],
    "city": request.form["city"],
    "reviews": [],
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": LAT_VALUE,
            "long": LONG_VALUE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know how i'd do this for a nested array with a nested object? 


photos: Array
 0 : Object
      height: 3024
      html_attributions: Array
           0: "<a 
href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110135647500030257709">A…"
       width: 4032

Comment: You can insert an array/list into mongnodb in a similar manner. Simply add a key to your doc dict with the value as the list. It'll be up to you to construct the list of dicts though if they're not already in a nice format.